# Matching numbers by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let $0<x \leq 1$, We define a function such that $f(x)=y=\frac{1}{x}$ which results $y \geq 1$ . We have infinitely many numbers between $0$ and $1$, so we can match any $x$ to a number $y$ greater than $1$ via $f(x)$. There are also infinitely many numbers greater than $1$. We can match the numbers between this two intervals one to one. Which intuitively results  that the number of elements of these two intervals are equal. I am confused. How can it be possible?

Comment: The idea of "number of elements" becomes fuzzier than our normal understanding when working with infinite sets.  The concept you're looking for is called the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of a set.  By exhibiting a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, it can be shown that the cardinality of any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.  You've exhibited a bijection between $[1,\infty)$ and $(0,1]$.

Comment: $x$ can not be $0.$ :)

Comment: It is possible, you have given a clear and succinct proof. There are several notions of equality of "size." Equal cardinality, the existence of a one-to-one correspondence, is a relatively weak one. In the sense of *measure*, the set of reals greater than $1$ is far larger than the set of reals in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: You already answered how it is possible and in fact true by demonstrating a bijection. The key is that the "measure" of sets (computed via lengths of intervals) and the "cardinality" of sets (isomorphism class under bijection, or "number of elements") are not the same notion of size, so there is no contradiction involved.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, confusion arises when a rigorous definition of a concept is missing. For this question we need to clarify precisely what the concept "*the number of elements*" (of a set) means.

For a set whose elements can be represented in a list, we assign a natural number, as its size or number of elements, to the set by counting, which can be described as follows. Counting is in fact a **one-to-one correspondence** (an injective and surjective function in mathematics language) between such a set and a set of natural numbers, of the form $\{ 1, \dots , n \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with the same size. For example, consider the set $\{ a, b, c, d, e \}$. We can establish the following correspondence:
\begin{gather*}
a \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 1\\
b \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 2\\
c \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 3\\
d \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 4\\
e \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 5
\end{gather*}

So the sets $\{ a, b, c, d, e \}$ and $\{ 1, 2,  3, 4, 5 \}$ are in one-to-one correspondence; the same size is denoted by $5$ (in general, the size of the set $\{ 1, \dots , n \}$ is denoted by $n$), which will be the size of any sets being in one-to-one correspondence with the set $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$. Such sets are called *finite* sets.

But, for sets whose elements cannot be represented in a list, this limited counting method does not work out; for example, one could not count, say, the set of all natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or the set of even natural numbers $E$ and then assign a natural number, as its size, to it. However, as mathematics **never** stops, the idea of one-to-one correspondence is generalized to such sets, noting that the idea is not limited to finite sets. In general, two sets are thought of having the same size if there exists a one-to-one correspondence (injective & surjective function) between the two sets. For example, the sets $\mathbb{N}$ and $E$ are in one-to-one correspondence by the injective and surjective function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to E, \, f(n) = 2n$:
\begin{gather*}
1 \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 2\\
2 \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 4\\
3 \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 6\\
4 \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 8\\
\, \, 5 \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 10\\
\vdots \qquad \vdots\\
\, \, n \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad 2n\\
\vdots \qquad \vdots
\end{gather*}

Sets that are not finite are called *infinite* sets

However, this generalization does not necessarily share *all* properties the case of finite sets has. The distinctive characteristic is that a finite set cannot be in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset of itself while infinite sets can, as observed in the example above: the set $E$ is a proper subset of the set $\mathbb{N}$. As a marginal consequence, the term "size" does not seem appropriate here because one usually thinks that a whole thing should have a greater size than its part, so the term *cardinal* is usually used instead.

As a result, when dealing with infinite sets, the picture of coincidence of two sets with the same cardinal in the same way as two line segments with the same length coincide should be discarded. So the set of real numbers greater than or equal to $1$, $[1, \infty )$, and the set of positive real numbers less than or equal to $1$, $(0, 1]$, have the same cardinal by the one-to-one correspondence $f \colon (0, 1] \to [1, \infty ), \, f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, without having the same length to coincide.